# (SOLVED) How do I make a throwing (using drag) system for items in my 2D game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, physics

I've looked near and far but I can't find a definitive answer to how I can do this. I'm using image GameObjects with dynamic Rigidbodies and 2D colliders. The dragging function works well but I can't get the items to fly off into the distance whenever you swipe the item. Here is my drag-and-drop code:

```
  [SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;
  private RectTransform rectTransform;
  private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;


  private void Awake() {
    rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  }

  public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    rigidbody.gravityScale = 0;
  }

  public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;

  }

  public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    rigidbody.gravityScale = 50;
  }
```

(sorry for the indent)

I tried this over and over with springs and stuff, and I thought it would throw the item across the screen when you swiped, but it either gives me irrelevant errors or makes no change. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! Here's my full script. I'll comment anything that I've changed.

```
[SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;
private RectTransform rectTransform;
private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
private SpringJoint2D _spring; // Just a reference to a spring

private void Awake() {
  rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
  rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

  _spring = GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>(); // Set the spring to the spring 
  //I put on my GameObject
  _spring.connectedAnchor = rectTransform.position; // Set the spring's 
  //connected anchor to my object's position
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
   rigidbody2d.gravityScale = 0;

   _spring.enabled = true; // Enable the spring (to track movement)
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {

   if(_spring.enabled == true) { // If the spring is on...
     Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition; // ... Get the mouse position 
     in world coordinates ... 
     _spring.connectedAnchor = mousePos; // .... and set the spring's 
     connected anchor to the mousePos variable.
   }

 }

 public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
   rigidbody2d.gravityScale = 50;
   _spring.enabled = false; // Disable the spring.
 }
```

Here are my spring settings:
Enable collision is false.
No connected Rigidbodies.
Don't auto-config connected anchor.
anchor is 0, 0.
(Don't worry about the connected anchor. It doesn't matter.)
Auto-config distance is  false.
distance is 0.005 (minimum).
Damping is 0.
Frequency is 2.
BF is infinity.

And that's all!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! can you mark your answer as accepted so people can quickly tell whether more elaboration is necessary?

Comment: @JacobStuligross ok sorry